# Is there a way to generate pure tone at a specfic sound pressure level in android?

Tags: android

I am new to Android and I am now finding a way to create pure at different frequencies and at different sound pressure level (dB SPL). I have been reading some other sample codes, however, many answers reflected that one must be calibrated before generating a tone of specific sound pressure level.

Is there any way to specify a tone's sound pressure level?

The magnitude can be find easily by certain method(is it?), but I don't know the mathematical relationship between magnitude and sound pressure. If I can convert magnitude to sound pressure, it will be easy to convert it into dB SPL

Comment: You can't generalize your code to produce same sound pressure on different mobiles as different sound hardware will create different out put on the same software input.

Comment: what if I consider also this variables?
is there any method to control this?

Comment: Consider it like a sound system. When you buy some high level sound system it has `different sound level` when you set the volume to MAX and different when you buy some low level sound system.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do this without calibration.

Theoretically a manufacturer could offer a device with calibration tables somehow made accessible, but there is little obvious demand for them to do so.  And don't forget that things like case covers, even dirt and aging could invalidate the calibration.  Or headsets.  Or even the infamous "you're holding it wrong!" - which was about antennas, but somewhat comparable issues apply.

Comment: thanks for your reply
it seems we need to consider many parameters in order to do this task....